# Corregir el error de Netbeans 8.2 EE Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans-8.2

Tengo un problema, acabo de instalar Netbeans y no me deja crear proyectos. Ya me había pasado lo mismo en windows pero ahí lo solucioné rápido, pero en Ubuntu no sé cómo hacerlo

Comment: Sería genial si a tu pregunta añades algún mensaje de error o advertencia que te esté lanzando el IDE, que pueda ayudar a identificar más rápido el problema o el comportamiento que está teniendo cuando deseas crear dicho proyecto

Comment: Los plugins estan activos??? `Tools --> Plugins --> Installed`y activar los modulos.

Comment: Sí, todos están activos.